# How is confidence interval computed for autocorrelation?

Tags: confidence-interval, autocorrelation

**TLDR;**

Does anybody know what formula the National Institute of Standards and Technology used to compute autocorrelation confidence interval in the Heat Flow Meter case study? My program fails to compute the same values.

**BACKGROUND**

I am writing a computer program that can compute the autocorrelation statistical values on large data-sets using streaming (think pipe and filter architecture). There are several challenges on this approach. First, I must understand the statistical algorithm, its approach, and its computations. Second, I must adapt its formulas to fit a streaming model. Third, I must validate the correctness of my computations.  The National Institute of Standards and Technology provides plenty of literature on statistics. I wrote a program for autocorrelation that almost computes the same values. However, I am having trouble computing the same confidence interval.

I am trying to duplicate the statistical calculations of the results the Heat Flow Meter Autocorrelation Case Study at the National Institute of Standards and Technology (NIST).

NIST provides documentation regarding autocorrelation at http://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/eda/section3/eda35c.htm

They also provide a case study at http://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/eda/section4/eda428.htm

However, I am yielding different results in MY COMPUTATIONS vs NIST COMPUTATIONS.

**MY COMPUTATIONS**

*lag*   *autocorrelation*
   0          1.000000
   1          0.280578
   2          0.195450
   3          0.051023
   4         -0.115508
   5        -0.145059
   6        -0.232383
   7        -0.175716
   8        -0.057883
   9         0.024602
 10      0.085815
 11      0.135373
 12       0.141751
 13       0.052049
 14       0.036990
 15      -0.045927
 16      -0.051406
 17      -0.102175
 18      -0.059514
 19      -0.065605
 20      -0.009268
 21      -0.115807
 22      -0.109947
 23       0.089912
 24      -0.005113
 25      -0.021593
 26      0.059731
 27      -0.004911
 28       0.002099
 29       0.002975
 30      -0.033521
 31      -0.037941
 32      -0.070626
 33      -0.100263
 34       0.047839
 35      -0.040888
 36       0.043585
 37       0.073654
 38       0.091946
 39       0.105621
 40       0.029907
 41       0.009842
 42       0.016926
 43       0.074423
 44      -0.001215
 45      -0.022047
 46      -0.004931
 47      -0.016225
 48       0.065377
 49       0.015420

mean: 0.02175
standard deviation: 0.16844816
sqrt(N) => sqrt(50) = 7.07106781

confidence interval => z * sd / sqrt(N) => 1.96 * 0.16845 / 7.07107 = 0.04669 with 95% of all values within lower-bound: -0.02494, upper-bound: 0.06844

alternate confidence interval => z / sqrt(N) => 1.96 / 7.07107 = 0.27719 with 95% of all values within lower-bound: -0.25544, upper-bound: 0.29893

confidence interval => z * sd / sqrt(N) => 2.575 * 0.16845 / 7.07107 = 0.06134 with 99% of all values within lower-bound: -0.03959, upper-bound: 0.08309

NIST COMPUTATIONS

On the NIST Quantatitive Output and Interpretation page, NIST states the following:

"The lag 1 autocorrelation, which is generally the one of greatest interest, is 0.280579. The critical values at the 5 % significance level are -0.087 and 0.087. This indicates that the lag 1 autocorrelation is statistically significant, so there is evidence of non-randomness."

QUESTION

Does anybody know what formula the National Institute of Standards and Technology used to compute autocorrelation confidence interval in the Heat Flow Meter case study? It is apparent that we are computing different confidence intervals. I do not know how NIST came up with the confidence interval -0.087 and 0.087.

Comment: NIST replied:

The formula used is at

[link](http://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/software/dataplot/refman1/auxillar/autoband.htm)

There are 2 different formulations used.  The first is used under the assumption
that the time series is completely random (i.e., there is no autocorrelation).  The
second is used in the context of ARIMA modeling.

The reference for these formulas is

      Box and Jenkins (1976), "Time Series Analysis: Forecasting and Control",
      Revised Edition, Holden Day, pp. 34-35.

Specifically, the formula for the variance for the first case is on page 35.

Answer (score 0):

I received a reply from NIST regarding this calculation. They answered it for me with this response:

1. The N is the size of the sample, not the number of lags.  So
    the correct value is 1.96/sqrt(195) = 0.140.
2. The 0.087 critical value is a **typo**.  Not sure where this comes
    from but the correct critical value is 0.140.  I will fix
    this today.   The plot is actually drawing the line at 0.140.

Comment: I would think that N should be the sample size minus the lags

Comment: It would be nice to know how to calculate confidence intervals of the parameter estimate, not just the critical values of statistical significance.